# Can I access to website using IP address

Tags: dns

I recently got to know about DNS (Domain Name System Or Domain Name Server) and how it works. I want to know - can I access to a website by using its IP address and how?
-ThankYou

Comment: I didn't get from there that's why I put up here.

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR:** It depends how the server is configured but probably not and I would not rely on it.

This is because the website you are trying to access is likely behind a reverse proxy or load balancer. The load balancer acts like a railroad switch depending on the hostname you use to connect to it.

For simplicity, imagine that `google.com` and `mail.google.com` are on the same server with the same IP: `192.168.1.1`.

If you were to try to connect directly to `http://192.168.1.1/`, how would the web server know which service you wanted?  *It wouldn't.*  In fact there are companies who's business is based solely around load balancing other companies' servers.

When you connect to a host with your browser, for example: `https://www.google.com`, your browser sends a special `HOST=www.google.com` header behind the scenes.  The load balancer processes this header and routes the request to the correct server (which may be on a completely different server, network, etc).

Digital Ocean has a great tutorial on how to [configure a basic virtual host for nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04).  This demonstrates the basics of what a multi-host configuration might look like.

If you don't want to mess with DNS servers, you could set up a local lab environment on your desktop simply by modifying your `hosts` file.  You can google where your operating systems hosts file is located.

If you have access to cURL, you can test the results like so:

```
# if you've configured a virtual host for mysite01.local on port 80 
curl --verbose --header 'Host: mysite01.local' 'http://127.0.0.1'

# if you've configured a virtual host for mysite02.local on port 80 
curl --verbose --header 'Host: mysite02.local' 'http://127.0.0.1'

# depending on your configuration this may return a 404 or point to one of your previous sites 
curl --verbose 'http://127.0.0.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can access any domain using IP address. Domain is just a name of website, IP address is the address of the page/website.
You can always ping website using command prompt:

```
ping www.google.com
```

You get one ip address which in this case is `216.58.197.78`. Now when you hit the ip address in browser you will be redirected to google.com.
You can think of DNS (Domain Name System) as a table which provides mapping between IP address(216.58.197.78) and domain name(www.google.com)

Comment: Not able to do so

Comment: no able ro do, u entered 216.58.197.78 in url

Comment: Downvoted.
Entering 216.58.197.78 in the browser does not do anything.