# Is there a way to make an ajax call to a specific IP by URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am writing a script that does a lookup for a domain, then will iterate through each IP for reachability.

For instance, if you look up google.com, there are 6 IPs.  I want to go to google.com, but force it to use each IP, returning 6 different results.

I have everything, except how do I use the IP?  If I just specify the IP, it fails as the servers don't respond to the IP - site is bound to the domain.

I am using npm & electron if that helps...

```
function checkConnection(myIP, myPort, myDomain) {
    var isAccessible = null;
    var url = "https://" + myDomain + ":" + myPort;
    console.log(myDomain + " check at "+ url);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "get",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        timeout : 1500,
        complete : function(xhr, responseText, thrownError) {
            if(xhr.status != "404") {
                isAccessible = true;
                console.log(myDomain + " check at "+ url + " passed");
                console.log(xhr);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                isAccessible = false;
                console.log(myDomain + " check at "+ url + " failed");
                console.log(xhr);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46563730/can-i-access-to-website-using-ip-address

Comment: never tried it but I suspect you could do it serverside by setting the host with wget, then the load balancer/reverse proxy will know how to route. `wget https://<IP> --header "Host: <DOMAIN>"`

Comment: You can't browserside https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46702/how-can-i-control-the-content-of-the-http-host-header-in-requests-issued-from-my